# What other scriptures created by other Vyasas?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, vyasa

I know Krishna Dvaipayana (present Veda Vyasa) wrote Puranas, Mahabharata and also Valmiki (24th Vyasa) wrote Ramayana.

Like this, I want to know about other scriptures created by other previous Vyasas.

Answer (score 0):

The list of Vyasas according to Sri Shiva Purana.;

**[Sri Shiva Purana 3.5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226401.html).:**

> *39. **In the twenty-sixth aeon, when Parāśara, becomes Vyāsa** I will be born as Sahiṣṇu after reaching the city Bhadravaṭa.*

Sage Parashara became the author of Sri Vishnu Purana.

[**Sri Vishnu Purana: Book 1: Chapter 1.:**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp035.htm)

> *Paráśara replied, ... Then arrived Pulastya, the son of Brahmá, who was received by my grandfather with the customary marks of respect. The illustrious brother of Pulaha said to me; Since, in the violence of animosity, you have listened to the words of your progenitor, and have exercised clemency, therefore you shall become learned in every science: since you have forborne, even though incensed, to destroy my posterity, I will bestow upon you another boon, and, you shall become the **author** of a summary of the Puráńas; you shall know the true nature of the deities, as it really is; and, whether engaged in religious rites, or abstaining from their performance, your understanding, through my favour, shall be perfect, and exempt from doubts. Then my grandsire Vaśisht́ha added; Whatever has been said to thee by Pulastya, shall assuredly come to pass.*

I hope this clarifies your queries.